# Suggestions on Approach to New Plugin I'm Stuck On

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin-menu, get-plugin-data

I'm a newbie plugin developer, and I've had an idea for what I though would be a simple to build debut plugin, but I seem to have reached a brick wall with it and wonder if anyone can suggest some alternative approaches or even tell me whether it's even possible.

The aim of the plugin was this: to create tool tips showing the plugin name, for any menu items in the Admin pages that were created by plugins (i.e. not part of the default WP install). So for example you might see the menu item: Users/Roles, and think 'where does that Roles item come from?' You'd then hover over the item, and a tool tip would pop up saying "Added by Members plugin", so you know that item was added by the Members plugin.

So at first I explored the `Walker` class, but this didn't seem to apply to menus in the admin. Next I looked for filters for the admin menu, to try and add an HTML title attribute into menu items created by plugins, but I didn't seem to be able to find any suitable filters.

I looked at the `$menu` and `$submenu` global variables in WP, but for some reason, some menu items that were present in the page weren't in these collections, in particular those created by the aforementioned Members plugin.

So finally I thought I would grab the array of plugins using the `get_plugins()` function, I then extracted the name of each plugin folder from this and guessed this would be the name of the plugin. I then passed this list of plugin names and their diplay names into javascript parameters for use by a jquery function, to see if it could find any of these plugin names in any of the html links or class names in the admin menus. It then added an html title attribute to any matched links and displayed it with the jquery `tooltip()` funtionality.

This worked partially, but since many of the plugin names do not appear in the links they create or even the titles of the menus they create, it's incomplete and so not very useful.

So I wonder if there's anything I've overlooked that could be a way to achieve this functionality more robustly?

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: this sounds like an impossible task as WP is too flexible to actually follow any specific pattern, especially using names as they can be translated, but I wonder what exactly is the use case for such a functionality?

Comment: to clarify it is possible, but for general solution you might need to parse the plugin's php files and or used backtrace to  figure out which file added a menu and then try to guess the plugin. both can be done, but do they worth the effort?

Comment: Thanks for your input @MarkKaplun. The use case has been my own frustration when I have installed many plugins to a WP site and then want to remove some I don't use. After a while I find I can forget which plugin is responsilble for which menu item, especially when a setting is not even in a menu but in a property page. So it would be handy to see exactly how a plugin has changed the mens etc. to quickly see if it's something I use or not.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins generate menu items by calling `add_management_page()`. Here they insert the slug that ends up in the menu. Usually this slug is the same as the plugin slug, but this is not mandatory. Hence your partial result when you tried this. You would have to scavenge all plugin files to find the slugs as @Mark Kaplun suggested.

Or you could override `add_management_page()`. Make sure your plugin is loaded as early as possible (use `add_action('muplugins_loaded', 'your_plugin_name',0);`), so all other plugins will use your version of `add_management_page()`.

Using PHP's `debug_backtrace` you can find the function that called your version of `add_management_page()`. Next you can find the path where that calling function originates with PHP's `ReflectionFunction`. Then you match the path with the list of plugins you got using `get_plugins()`. This gives you all the information you need for your tooltip.

So, it's a hell of a job and I certainly didn't try it out.

Comment: Edited just to correct a word

Comment: Thanks @cjbj that's very helpful I shall take a look at trying that.

Comment: Quick question @cjbj - you mentioned overriding `add_management_page()` - however if I try and redefine that function I get a PHP error. I looked into the PHP `override_function` but that seems to require a PECL extension which I'm not sure can be packed into a plugin. Is that what you meant or maybe I misunderstood something? Ta for any help.

Comment: @Jelnet Perhaps you should look deeper, see which functions are called by add_management_page. Maybe there's a hook there which you can use. Perhaps even something that operates directly on the datastructure. As I said: this really is very complex stuff that I didn't try. I can point in a gerenal direction, but there's no guarantee for success.